# Meteor Expected "div" end tag - Any possibility to bypass this?

Tags: meteor

I am trying to put the start of a div in a "header" template and the end in a "footer" template.
Unfortunately meteor shows the following during the building process and fails to start:

```
Your app is crashing. Here's the latest log.
=> Meteor server restarted
Errors prevented startup:
While building the application:
file.html:22: Expected "div" end tag
```

What is the correct way of implementing divs that start in one template and end in another?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't, not sure why you'd want that ?

Comment: This kind of behaviour is generally not advised. If necessary, ask another question about your initial issue, not what you tried to achieve it. It seems you have an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). - Oh, and by the way, there's no need to say "thanks" here, we're all here to help so it's considered noise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extend your templating as far as necessary.

Without an example of your code, I can only make an assumption of what you're trying to do.

```
<body>
   <div class="container">
      <div id="another-div">
         {{> header}}
      </div>
      {{> footer}}
   </div>
</body>

<template name="header">
   <nav id="header">
      <!-- content -->
   </nav>
</template>

<template name="footer">
   <footer id="footer">
      <!-- content -->
   </footer>
</template>
```

That being said, an example of your code in your post will help specify the answer.